# npm failing inside docker for windows through gradle task

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, gradle, npm

The project I'm working on is to automate a webhook with gradle and jenkins. I'm using a docker container for jenkins. I keep getting this error:

```
    Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/train-schedule
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/anuarhage/cicd-pipeline- 
train-schedule-jenkins # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/anuarhage/cicd-pipeline- 
train-schedule-jenkins
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/anuarhage/cicd-pipeline- 
train-schedule-jenkins +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 638b87c61e0341b96748943ec5583b1f1e0115e1 
(refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 638b87c61e0341b96748943ec5583b1f1e0115e1
Commit message: "Update README.md"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 638b87c61e0341b96748943ec5583b1f1e0115e1 # 
timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[train-schedule] $ /var/jenkins_home/workspace/train-schedule/gradlew build
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:nodeSetup UP-TO-DATE
:npmSetup FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':npmSetup'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 
'/var/jenkins_home/workspace/train-schedule/.gradle/nodejs/node-v9.11.1- 
linux-x64/bin/node''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

From the error I gathered it was a path issue and added several paths using docker exec -it 'filename' bash. None of them worked.

The paths I've added are:

```
PATH=$PATH:~.:.:/:/usr
```

I've also tried adding a dockerfile in several different places with 'HOME=.' in it to no avail

This is the build.gradle script:

```
plugins {
  //inlude the nodeJS plugin to execute nodejs and npm tasks
  id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
}

node {
        download = true
        version = "9.11.1"
        npmVersion = "5.6.0"
}

//declare a build task
task build

//declare a task to create a zip of the app
task zip(type: Zip) {
        from ('.') {
                include "*"
                include "bin/**"
                include "data/**"
                include "node_modules/**"
                include "public/**"
                include "routes/**"
                include "views/**"
        }
        destinationDir(file("dist"))
        baseName "trainSchedule"
}

//declare task dependencies
build.dependsOn zip
zip.dependsOn npm_build
npm_build.dependsOn npm_test
npm_test.dependsOn npmInstall
```

I've been at this for <13 hours and I can confidently say I am as confused as I was at the beginning, any guidance is much appreciated.

If any more info is necessary I can provide it readily.

Thank you

I dug through the gradle-node-plugin and this is what I found

```
class NpmSetupTask
    extends DefaultTask
{
    public final static String NAME = 'npmSetup'

    private NpmExecRunner runner

    private NodeExtension config

    protected List<?> args = []

    private ExecResult result

    NpmSetupTask()
    {
        dependsOn( SetupTask.NAME )

        this.group = 'Node'
        this.description = 'Setup a specific version of npm to be used by 
        the build.'
        this.enabled = false

        this.runner = new NpmExecRunner( this.project )
    }

    @Input
    Set<String> getInput()
    {
        def set = new HashSet<>()
        set.add( getConfig().download )
        set.add( getConfig().npmVersion )
        set.add( getConfig().npmWorkDir )
        return set
    }

    @OutputDirectory
    File getNpmDir()
    {
        return getVariant().npmDir
    }

    @Internal
    ExecResult getResult()
    {
        return this.result
    }

    @Internal
    protected getConfig()
    {
        if ( this.config != null )
        {
            return this.config
        }

        this.config = NodeExtension.get( this.project )
        return this.config
    }

    @Internal
    protected getVariant()
    {
        return getConfig().variant
    }

    List<?> getArgs()
    {
        return this.args
    }

    @Internal
    void setArgs( final Iterable<?> value )
    {
        this.args = value.toList()
    }

    void setIgnoreExitValue( final boolean value )
    {
        this.runner.ignoreExitValue = value
    }

    void setExecOverrides( final Closure closure )
    {
        this.runner.execOverrides = closure
    }

    @TaskAction
    void exec()
    {
        this.runner.arguments.addAll( this.args )
        this.result = this.runner.execute()
    }

    void configureVersion( String npmVersion )
    {
        if ( !npmVersion.isEmpty() )
        {
            logger.debug( "Setting npmVersion to ${npmVersion}" )
            setArgs( ['install', '--global', '--no-save', '--prefix', 
getVariant().npmDir, "npm@${npmVersion}"] )
            enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the task `npmSetup` doing?

Comment: Hey @frhd, thanks for the reply. I updated my post with the source code from the plugin.

Comment: Can you try running the build again with `--stacktrace` appended and post the output?